# MySQL UPDATE to replace text in LONGTEXT field

Tags: query, mysql-5

I have a WordPress table `wp_posts` and I'd like to run an UPDATE that will replace a url from my old domain to my new domain.

For example, let's say that one record in the field `post_content` has the following content:

```
This is my <a href="http://www.my-old-site.com/link/to/some/page">old web</a> site.
<img src="http://www.my-old-site.com/wp-content/upload/2012/02/my-image-file.jps />
```

I'd like that to become:

```
This is my <a href="http://www.my-new-site.com/link/to/some/page">old web</a> site.
<img src="http://www.my-new-site.com/wp-content/upload/2012/02/my-image-file.jps />
```

I've tried the following query

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS w` 
SET w.post_content = REPLACE(w.post_content, 'my-old-site.com', 'my-new-site.com');
```

but I don't get any result.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't get any result"? Is there an error message, or does the string just not get updated? I just tried your above test case on MySQL 5.1.61 & it worked fine. "Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0"

Comment: Found this searching for "mysql longtext find and replace" and I'm also updating all old wordpress posts from an old URL to a new one. Small world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an error in your query near

```
AS w`
```

Alias name "w" should instead be

```
`w`
```

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS `w` 
SET w.post_content = REPLACE(w.post_content, 'my-old-site.com', 'my-new-site.com');
```

Comment: You don't even need to use quotes round the alias. UPDATE wp_posts AS w SET w.post_content = REPLACE(w.post_content, 'my-old-site.com', 'my-new-site.com'); works fine

Comment: Yes Phil, it can also be used without rounding with quote. I written that way because one quote was missing in the query.